# Share a View between ComponentViews

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I wonder if there is any way to share a View between ComponetViews.
I like to share a Menu between some ComponetViews, I have tried to share it as PartalView but it seems it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partail view can be shared between View Components.

You can check this demo:

**Two ViewComponents:**

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewComponentSample.Models.TodoItem
<h3>First View Component</h3>   
@await Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Shared/_partial.cshtml")  //partial here
```

**partial view:**

```
@{
List<ViewCompFinal.Models.Menu> menulist = new List<ViewCompFinal.Models.Menu>
{
    new ViewCompFinal.Models.Menu{ Name="Beer"},
    new ViewCompFinal.Models.Menu{ Name="Beef"}
}; 
}

@foreach (var item in menulist)
{
     @item.Name<br/>
}
```

Result:

[image]

You can check how to use partial view and viewComponent here:

[partial view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[view component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: thanks a lot, I have tried to share a partial view but I have got the error that said it couldn't find view but view was there maybe I did a mistake in the path, where it should be? components are in the Views/Shared folder but where the partial view should be to be found by them? is there any rule for location?

Comment: @PariaShiri I put the partial in Shared folder, and you can check the rule in that [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0#partial-view-discovery) And if you still have problem, maybe you should share your code so i can reproduce it.